# Recieve "HTTP ERROR 500" when attempting to create a database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm encountering an issue when I try to use php to create a database. I've google around, ensured that the user has permission to create a database and it still doesn't work.

I'm able to use PHP to create and modify tables once I create the database manually, but I'd like this code to run in PHP for personal reasons.

Here's the code, just in case I'm missing something.

*edit: grammar

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "user";
$password   = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE inkflow_backend";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "Database created successfully, <a href="setup2.php">continue.</a>";
} else{
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error . "Please contact the developer or your network administrator.";
}

//Close connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What error message do you get on executing the code? Maybe you need to check the PHP error log file

Comment: Another user pointed out my error, it was just syntax. I forgot to escape my quotes in my continue message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the quotes that you're using when printing a link to setup2.php.

They are causing a syntax error. Just putting a backslash before them would solve the problem:

```
<a href=\"setup2.php\" ...
```